# How to catch and log "Aw, Snap" error in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is it possible handle and report to logging system when app crashes in Google Chrome with "Aw, Snap" message?

[image]

It seems that Chrome doesn't call onerror message when an error like that appears. Is there a way to catch it and do something (e.g. POST request) to log it in our system?

Comment: I don't think you can. That happens when the browser is unable to continue running the script for some reason. If the script can't run, it can't catch errors.